# /\s+$/u performs really bad if string contains many spaces in the middle

Tags: php, regex, performance, php-8, php-8.1

Consider this string (notice the horizontal scroll - the string is long):

```
$content = 'Xxxxxx xx xxxx xxxxxx/xxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxx xx xxx   XXXXXXX/XXXXX XXXX   XXXXXXX XXXX   XXXXXX                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               XXXXX XXXXXX   XXXXXX   XXXXXX XXXXX   XXXXXX';
```

I have my own `mb_trim()` function to support unicode strings, but I found it's performing really bad for this string in specific.

After debugging, I realized that it's just the "end-of-string" bit that doesn't perform, while "beginning-of-string" is fine.

So, just doing this (minimal code):

```
$trim = preg_replace('/\s+$/u', '', $content);
```

This takes 2s ~ 3s.
But even without the `u` modifier, it still takes ~1.60s.

If I replace the spaces in the middle with some letter, the `preg_replace` will take 0s.

**Is there a way to fix this performance issue?**

It's funny that if I run this:

```
$trim = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/u', ' ', $content);
$trim = preg_replace('/\s+$/u', '', $trim);
```

This will run fast.
But I don't understand why are the spaces in the middle of the string a problem for an "end-of-string" regex. I'd think it would be optimized in a way that it would only look at the end of the string and not in the middle.

--

UPDATE - This seems to take the 2s on the server running AlmaLinux (even though it has a very good CPU and RAM) and on a Docker container running CentOS 7 on a Windows. But if I run the script on the Windows itself, it runs instantly. It also runs fast on 3v4l.

I tried on another Linux host running PHP 7.4, and it took 5.4s.

I wonder what could be causing the hang on the Linux systems above?

Comment: First preg works fine for me `time php8.1 test.php` -> `Executed in 76.09 millis, usr time 35.12 millis, sys time 22.40 millis`

Comment: Strange.. It takes 3s on my Linux server (huge CPU & RAM) and on my Windows locally.

Comment: FYI: PHP 8.1.10 (cli) (built: Sep 18 2022 10:26:02) (NTS)

Comment: PHP 8.1.7 here. Seems to be pretty fast also on 3v4l, even if I use my version. I'll continue to investigate...

Comment: Ok. When I say I run on Windows above, I meant a Docker container which runs CentOS 7. The server runs AlmaLinux. Both those take 2+ seconds, whether it's through PHP-FPM or CLI. If I run the same script on my Windows (not in docker), it takes 0s...

Comment: Have you tried with a [possessive quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html): `\s++$`

Comment: Thank you. That's very interesting... `/\s++$/u` seems to run instantly! Never heard about "possessive". I'll have a read. But do you have any idea why the original regex would not perform well on the various Linux systems, but does on Windows and 3v4l? Thank you!

Comment: @Nuno I don't know why this runs well on windows or 3v4l because there is a whole lot of backtracking even [in much shorter strings already (demo)](https://regex101.com/r/ZpAOGv/1). See the steps counter or click on left side the debugger. Guess these environments where it "performs well" have just set a pcre.backtrack_limit at a low value.

Comment: @bobblebubble - In 3v4l, backtrack_limit = 1000000, same as mine. If I put a backtrack_limit that is too low, the regex fails and I get NULL. Thank you - really appreciate the time. I can see in that demo how using `++` reduces the steps a lot!

Comment: I'm surprised that there appears to be no PHP [wrapper for RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Install)

Comment: @jhnc - interesting! Didn't know about it. Thank you. But based on its description, it might not fix the issue discussed here. https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/WhyRE2

Comment: RE2 would definitely help here: https://regex101.com/r/eb4RUo/1

Comment: @Nuno I just stumpled upon [this blogpost](https://mamchenkov.net/wordpress/2016/07/21/the-regex-that-killed-stackoverflow/) that seems related to your question :) Looks like you're not the only one having struggled with this!

Comment: Ah, nice! That was exactly the same thing! :) thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Late comes my answer! The bad performance is a result from a lot of [*backtracking*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/backtracking-in-regular-expressions) if the input contains many whitespaces which are *not at the end*. Looks like even Stack Overflow faced some similar problem. I stumbled upon this old blogpost recently: [The RegEx that killed StackOverflow](https://mamchenkov.net/wordpress/2016/07/21/the-regex-that-killed-stackoverflow/)

**The most obvious and first idea** to use a [possessive quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) for reducing backtracking:

```
\s++$
```

Using [this demo-input at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7SpJIo/1) it shows almost hundert times fewer steps [than without](https://regex101.com/r/E9LOw6/1).

---

**With a little trick to  let consume** everything until the last `\S` *non-whitespace* even better:

```
^(?s)(?>.*\S\K)?\s+$
```

[Getting it down to just 20 steps](https://regex101.com/r/DJP93X/1) from initially more than 200k steps with the demo input.

- The [`s` flag](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) (*single line*) makes the dot also match newlines
- `(?>` [atomic group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) `)` for failing fast if no whitespace at the end
- [`\K` resets](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) beginning of the reported match after the last `\S`

---

[Here a little PHP benchmark at tio.run](https://tio.run/##jZFfb4IwFMXf@yluGhLLrIjbo6LZ25K9mPg4NoLlKnXyJ23ZTJb51Vkp@oDJEnkot5z2nHt/1HndtovV@mVNyHQK20YeMzCoDWijZLknnn1DBJTOCdlVinkyCufgyUX0GLpiPPYJgJMOTjpcpUMvATiPIOosE4U1poZRoBxUWmZsFvJZGPp@QE@nU1x2OXedn3f9Tu573GyF1ALq1BhUpSZeN2Ry3doJ30bnWI@984i74lJ9sNUyeIg38au/crIevfckMBU5u3F53sDgi09@LACvMNa/kEJVRhbIjGrQtm@FEr@Tnm@tcN/NekwFDl25Zc8dQncHRV4NQwIal9ESaKCqxvK5yZnYdP5k6YJG0eMFsDREjuIT5A6wzKDaXX432LXAzB75SlWSNUXNdLO1Grv2yiezDn7fB/0PuAv6bds/) for comparing the  performance of all three variants.
**An alternative** for other regex flavors can be to replace [`^([\S\s]*\S)?\s*$`](https://regex101.com/r/kF22qB/1) with [`$1`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) (or `\1`).